# how to increase the score in cocos2d android when two sprites gets deleted

Tags: android, game-physics, cocos2d-android

I have a sprite(image) when it collide with another score should be increament by 10, related code is given in the update method, but instead of this it increases randomly. 
here's my code.

```
public void update(float dt)
{
    LinkedList<CCSprite> projectilesToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();
    for (CCSprite projectile : _projectiles)
    {
        CGRect projectileRect = CGRect.make(projectile.getPosition().x - (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                                            projectile.getPosition().y - (projectile.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                                            projectile.getContentSize().width,
                                            projectile.getContentSize().height);



        LinkedList<CCSprite> targetsToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();
        for (CCSprite target : _targets)
        {
            CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                            target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
                                            target.getContentSize().width,
                                            target.getContentSize().height);

            if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
                targetsToDelete.add(target);
            myscore += 10;
            showLabel(myscore);


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After increasing the myscore by 10 you need to update it like this

```
myscore += 10; 
updateTable(myscore); 
showLabel(myscore); 
addTarget();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your score increase should be within the if:

```
for (CCSprite target : _targets)
{
    CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                    target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
                                    target.getContentSize().width,
                                    target.getContentSize().height);

    if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect)){
        targetsToDelete.add(target);
        myscore += 10;
        showLabel(myscore);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have placed the code for it inside the "if" statement only. @HaIR